# Wix remove old service when upgrade mode

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer

I have wix installer, which install some services by using ServiceInstall command in wix config file. Now one of these services not needed and should be removed. When I run installer on computer where old version already was installed it replaces files, but not removes old service and also not remove all dependencies.
How to remove old service when installer run in upgrade mode and remove dependencies on this service?
Thanks

Comment: Did https://stackoverflow.com/a/28816443/2298578 work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are doing a major upgrade, it's the uninstall of the older product that removes the service, and that uninstall should also have a ServiceControl element with Remove set to uninstall. So if the uninstall of that older product uninstalls the service and its files then you should be good to go. In the new upgrade install just don't include the components that have the service and the dependencies you refer to, assuming you mean Dlls and assemblies.